# "Microsoft Azure Backup encountered an internal error" when creating backup-vault via python sdk

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to create backup vaults from yaml configuration with python azure sdk. [This is the documentation of the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-dataprotection/azure.mgmt.dataprotection.operations.backupvaultsoperations?view=azure-python-preview#azure-mgmt-dataprotection-operations-backupvaultsoperations-begin-create-or-update)

I'm using the azure-mgmt-dataprotection package to run the following code:

```
vault_properties = data_clt.backup_vaults.models.BackupVault(storage_settings=([None, None]))
vault_create = data_clt.backup_vaults.begin_create_or_update(backup.name, resource_group,                                                                              
                                                             parameters=BackupVaultResource(
                                                                 e_tag=None,
                                                                 identity=None,
                                                                 location=location,
                                                                 tags={},                                                                                   
                                                                 properties=vault_properties
                                                              ))
vault_create_result = vault_create.result()
```

`backup.name` and `resource_group` are read out of a yaml file and are correct. `resource_group` exists and `backup.name` is not used yet. Running the code, I get this error:

```
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (CloudInternalError) Microsoft Azure Backup encountered an internal error.
Code: CloudInternalError
Message: Microsoft Azure Backup encountered an internal error.
Additional Information:Type: UserFacingError
Info: {
    "message": "Microsoft Azure Backup encountered an internal error.",
    "recommendedAction": [
        "Wait for a few minutes and then try the operation again. If the issue persists, please contact Microsoft support."
    ],
    "details": null,
    "code": "CloudInternalError",
    "target": "",
    "innerError": null,
    "isRetryable": false,
    "isUserError": false,
    "properties": {
        "ActivityId": "*****"
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea how this could be fixed?